# Sonar C plugin — parser errors in include files

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, sonarqube

I am using Sonar C plugin, and I have a standard header file `stdafx.h` which includes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Now when I do the sonar run, it complains about these files are missing and parser error like `__declspec (dllexport)` etc.

So I had done like this

```
sonar.cfamily.library.directories=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.0/Include/um/,C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/include/
```

But now there are more parser errors on many files inside these header files.

Could anyone tell me how to do the analysis correctly?

Comment: Please add vc++ and visual studio in tag section to get quick help.

Answer (score 1):

Please contact the official support for commercial plugins.

In any case you should look at the plugin documentation page which tells you to use build-wrapper for header files resolution.

Comment: Answers should not consist only of links. If the link changes, the answer becomes invalid. Please include the main idea/suggestion of the resolution. Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer